# Procedure for restricting user from typing in php url

Tags: php

I've got a database where you can load details of a candidate through the following get request url: `database/candidates/?loadcandidate=n` where n is the id of the candidate to load.

Is there a common practice where you can add something to the get request which would prevent my users from being able to type in any id to access the details of candidates? I want them to only be able to access the candidate page from my search results or by bookmarking the candidate page and revisiting it later.

I could probably figure out my own eccentric way of doing this, but I'm wondering if there is a common procedure?

Comment: There is no way to prevent someone from fiddling with the url. Your back-end code should either not require the query parameter at all (e.g. keep the ID in the session somewhere), or have appropriate filters that simply disallows access to loadcandidates that the user isn't allowed to see.

Comment: I was thinking of maybe adding some cryptic checksum to the end which would be impossible to figure out without the key, but your method seems to be more elegant.

Comment: There's also no reason to have it in the URL, you could set it via a POST variable or Cookie, and then it's out of the URL entirely.

Comment: @STLMikey but still spoofable.

Comment: @STLMikey That offers no security at all

Comment: @user2721465 What you're suggesting, signing URLs with some sort of authorization hash, isn't uncommon.  But what happens if you want to revoke access at some point?  What if you don't want that URL to work for everyone that knows it?  You should really be checking the user's authorization on each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Get* requests are *get* requests and you can't prevent users from changing *get* request variables.

But reading between the lines, I think the solution you're looking for is obfuscating (hiding/cloaking the intended meaning of) the userid so that it can't just be plainly accessible via changing the id incrementally, (e.g., ?loadcandidate=1/2/3/4/5/6...).

In this case, try assigning a user code so that it would be harder to pull up candidates just by guessing the ID.

Just as a simple example (which by no means should be used for production) try simple MD5 hashing and get the first 6 digit substring.

Example:

```
1 = c4ca42
2 = c81e72
3 = eccbc8
...

database/candidates/?loadcandidate=c4ca42 will pull up candidate with user id = 1.
```

So that when you access database/candidates/?loadcandidate=n, n will be something much more difficult to guess, thereby decreasing the number of random lookups exponentially. Of course this will all depend on how *random* the obfuscation/code actually is.

Hope this helps!